# Convert images into avi with Raspberry Pi

Tags: avconv, mencoder, avi

I'm following this page: [Creating Timelapse Videos With The Raspberry Pi Camera](http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2013/05/creating-timelapse-videos-with-the-raspberry-pi-camera/).

But every time I try to make the video, I get this error:

[image: ss of error]

*original: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApIJ0.png*

Specifically this command from the output above:

```
$ avconv -r 10 -i pic_%04d.png -r 10 -vcodec libx264 -crf 20 -g 15 \
      -vf crop=2592:1458,scale=1280:720 timelapse.mp4
...
...
Output #0, mp4, to 'timelapse.mp4':
Output file #0 does not contain any stream
```

Also when using `mencoder`, following this page: [6.8. Encoding from multiple input image files (JPEG, PNG, TGA, etc.)](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/HTML/en/menc-feat-enc-images.html):

[image: ss of error]

*original:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/svNLx.png*

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

I just used this command to convert a stack of `.jpg` files to an `.mp4` file using `ffmpeg`. The switches should be similar enough.

```
$ ~/ffmpeg -r 10 -i pics_series2/01-2013110216%02d00-snapshot.jpg -c:v libx264 \
   -crf 20 -g 15 -vf crop=200:300,scale=352:288 timelapse.mp4
```

Let me know if that worked. Also you can download the statically built version of `ffmpeg` so there's literally nothing to install. It's a `.zip` file which contains 2 executables, `ffmpeg` being one of them. That's what I used to do this here.

- http://ffmpeg.gusari.org/static/

#### References

- [Segment format is not working - Output file #0 does not contain any stream](http://ffmpeg-users.933282.n4.nabble.com/Segment-format-is-not-working-Output-file-0-does-not-contain-any-stream-td4535688.html)
- [ffmpeg - 5.4 Main options](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Main-options)

Comment: It doesn't get `-c:v`

Comment: @Coolcrab - I understand, but can you get a .mp4 video using my switches instead? Once we confirm this then I'd start to add back the switches until we isolate the troublesome one(s). BTW, `-c:v X` is an alias for `-vcodec X`. http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html